# Win32 send sync events to other process

Tags: c++, winapi, d

I am trying to write a program that allows me to move the camera in Dota 2 more intuitively. While holding space it simulates the middle mouse button, and when the cursor reaches the screen border it jumps back to the center. Centering the cursor looks like this (simplified):

```
PostMessage(w, WM_KEYUP, VK_MBUTTON, 0);
PostMessage(w, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MAKELPARAM(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2));
SetCursorPos(screenHeight/2, screenHeight/2)
PostMessage(w, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_MBUTTON, 0);
```

`w` is the window handle of Dota 2. The problem is that when this occurs, Dota still thinks the button is down, and so the camera jumps. I made it work partially by simulating key events with SendInput instead of sending messages directly, but that required a pause of 10ms between events and that is not what I want. Is there a way to see whether a message has been processed by another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Games usually use DirectInput for mouse input, which will give them the true state of the mouse button.  `GetAsyncKeyState` also will check the actual mouse button state.

Your messages won't have much (or any) effect if the game is using other mouse processing mechanisms.

You can try using `SendInput` instead, which changes some of the internal states which Windows reports to applications.

Comment: Note that `SendInput`, as opposed to SM/PM, requires you to have the app running in foreground. From what I read, this won't be an issue for the OP though...

Comment: @Sebastian: Correct, because `SendInput` actually manipulates the system mouse device which is shared between all applications.

Comment: As I said this requires a rather large delay between input to be recognized which is not ideal (and weird, because usually windows doesn't just drop fast input). I kind of have a solution now though, I keep track of an internal cursor that moves opposite to the actual cursor, and I reset it to that internal cursor position after a certain tick. This allows me to go the same direction quite fast. Here's the logic, if anyone's interested http://pastebin.com/kRrYXT7W

Answer (score 0):

SendMessage (and SendMessageTimeout) indicate in their return value whether or not the message has been processed.